# WEKA - Force the same classification distribution as the training set when testing

Tags: weka

I am using Weka (training various classifiers such as *SimpleLogistic, BayesNet*) for a 3 class classification problem. In my training set, my data takes the following class distribution:

**Training set**

- **Class A:** 50% of instances
- **Class B:** 25% of instances
- **Class C:** 25% of instances

When I train various classification models I almost always get (roughly) the same classification distribution:

**Test set predictions**

- **Class A:** 60% of instances
- **Class B:** 2% of instances
- **Class C:** 38% of instances

Class B is essentially never predicted by my models.

**Question**

Is there a way in Weka to force the classifier to match the classification distribution as seen in the training set? 
*(i.e. force a 50/25/25 classification distribution in my example)*

Comment: Isn't that a kind of bias you are trying to apply? In this way you are telling the model: I have seen training data it has 50-25-25, so make your assumptions 50-25-25. Am I right?

Comment: I guess so, but I think that there is a chance it may improve my results. Almost never predicting class B is unsatisfactory in my scenario. Further, each classifier produces some probability for each class, so I guess all I want to do is map the top X% for each class to match the distribution of the training phase. Maybe I am talking rubbish but I just feel the classification distribution is not good enough and was wondering if there are any techniques to overcome this.

Comment: But this bias is not acceptable since you are tuning your algorithm by seeing the distributions in training data to get better performance on test data. This is not supported in ML community. First, the approach is not rational and second, you may get better results but still have low bias high variance in your model.

Comment: Ok thank you, ill close the question

Comment: I don't think you need to close it. People may have different opinions. And we can learn from almost anything!